# Bash - assign array into variable as string

Tags: bash, shell, variable, array

I have this code, it prints the correct result, but I can't figure out how to get the echo from the last line into a variable.

```
# hostname is 'tech-news-blog-324344' . Setting it into array host_name_array
IFS='-' read -r -a host_name_array <<< "$(hostname)" 
#removing the last part of string after last "-"
unset 'host_name_array[${#host_name_array[@]}-1]'
( IFS=$'-'; echo "${host_name_array[*]}" )  
#result is 'tech-news-blog'
```

How could get the value of the last line into a variable? 
I've tried the following:

```
( IFS=$'-'; URL="${host_name_array[*]}" )
```

But I get the result "tech news blog" with spaces between pieces of array instead of '-'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `IFS='-' read -r -a host_name_array <<< "$(hostname)"` is ran, the array is `(tech news blog 324344)`.

After the final element is removed with  `unset 'host_name_array[${#host_name_array[@]}-1]'`,  the array is `(tech news blog)`.

So, to get this to echo `tech-news-blog`, some substitution will have to be done, since  `echo "${host_name_array[*]}"` will yield `tech news blog`:

With tr: `echo "${host_name_array[*]}" | tr ' ' '-'`

sed: `echo "${host_name_array[*]}" | sed 's/ /-/g'`

Comment: Both the echo works, but if I try to set that result into a variable and reuse it I get from the variable the string with spaces

Comment: `var=$(echo "${host_name_array[*]}" | tr ' ' '-')`, but I think @heemayl's solution is better, since it is much less bulky and awkward.

Comment: When I echo the $var I get the string with spaces for some reason

Comment: About his answer, I have the same issue there when I echo the $var I get the string with spaces

Comment: Is IFS still set to '-'? If so, that may be the cause; reset it with `unset IFS`.

Comment: Using `echo` with `tr`/`sed` is silly here. `"${array[*]}"` does join the elements on the first character of IFS. Here you're joining with spaces and converting all spaces to dashes instead of just joining with dash in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by outputting the elements separated by `-`, and then strip off the last `-` by parameter expansion:

```
$ var=$(printf '%s-' "${host_name_array[@]}")

$ echo "$var"
foo-bar-spam-egg-

$ var="${var%-}"

$ echo "$var"
foo-bar-spam-egg
```

Also you need `${host_name_array[@]}` instead of `${host_name_array[*]}` to prevent outputting the elements as a whole separated by first character of `IFS`.

---

What you are trying to do can be achieved by a simple parameter expansion:

```
${var%-*}
```

**Example:**

```
$ var=$(hostname)

$ echo "${var%-*}"
```

Comment: The echo outputs correctly, but if I try to put into a variable and use the variable, I get the string with spaces "tech news blog". How could I set the string "tech-blog-news" into a variable and re-use it?

Comment: Wow, this is strong! Why did you not use `printf -v var "%s-" ...` syntax?

Comment: @F.Hauri You know what, thanks for reminding me; i always tend to forget that :)

Comment: @heemayl Using `var=$(printf...` **implie** one fork to *subshell*, where `printf -v ...` let you use builtin `printf` and set `var` without forks!  This is a lot quicker.

Comment: @F.Hauri I was serious there :) You are absolutely right :)

Answer (score 2):

`(...)` introduces a subshell. So `$URL` wouldn't be set after that (still have the value it had before the subshell). You want:

```
IFS=-
read -r -a host_name_array <<< "$(hostname)" 
unset 'host_name_array[${#host_name_array[@]}-1]'
URL="${host_name_array[*]}"
```

`"${host_name_array[*]}"` joins the elements on the arrays on the first character of `$IFS` just like `"$*"` does in standard `sh`.

If the reason why you're using a subshell is because you don't want to modify `$IFS` globally, you could do that in a function where you give `$IFS` a local scope:

```
f() {
  local IFS=-
  ...
}
f
```

Or use command substitution that also creates a subshell but allows passing data to the parent shell:

```
URL=$(IFS=-; printf '%s\n' "${host_name_array[*]}")
```

Here though I'd use standard `sh` expansion to remove that trailing component:

```
URL=$(uname -n) # uname -n is the standard equivalent of hostname
URL=${URL%-*}
```

It has several advantages over the above:

- it works even if the text contains newline characters (very unlikely for host names here though);
- if the text doesn't contain `-`, it doesn't remove anything;
- it is more efficient. `read <<< $(hostname)` means running `hostname`, read its output through a pipe, storing that in a temp file and have `read` read the first line of that;
- it doesn't clobber the variable namespace with those temporary variables
- it is shorter;
- it is portable. No need to install `bash` to run that code. The system's `sh` will suffice.

In any case, [remember  to quote your variables](/q/171346) when using them in list contexts:

```
printf '%s\n' "$URL"
```

When doing:

```
echo $URL
```

You're invoking the split+glob operator. So, if `$IFS` still contains `-`, that `$URL` would be split on `-`, and `echo` would output those words separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

#### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) specific answer: whipe *forks*!

As this already use bashisms, `sed`, `tr` or any other external tool are useless:

```
IFS='-' read -r -a host_name_array < <(hostname)
#removing the last part of string after last "-"
unset host_name_array[${#host_name_array[@]}-1]

shorted=${host_name_array[*]}
echo ${shorted// /-}
```

#### Or simplier:

This is a lot shorter, quicker and simplier:

```
read myvar < <(hostname)
echo ${myvar%-*}
```

And if really you need `host_name_array` for other reasons:

```
read shorted < <(hostname)
host_name_array=(${shorted//-/ })
shorted=${shorted%-*}
```

So you have an array **and** a shorted hostname:

```
declare -p host_name_array shorted
```

will return something like:

```
declare -a host_name_array='([0]="tech" [1]="news" [2]="blog" [3]="324344")'
declare -- shorted="tech-news-blog"
```